# What's the point of IntelliJ Local History "Put Label"?

Tags: intellij-idea

I see that I can put a label on a File Local History in IntelliJ, but is there a way to revert a file back to a specific label after making changes to it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is useful to "label" changes in different groups. When you run <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> and type `show history`, it will list all the labelled and non-labelled changes. You may select a label and by right clicking you may `revert` it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Think of a label as a "save point". For example, if you're at a good working point in your code, and you are about to start refactoring, adding a label gives you a perfect revert target in case things go awry. It basically replaces copying all the code to another file as backup, or arbitrarily having to commit to source control midway through a change.